# Creating VPC in AWS using Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, vpc

The following shows my Ansible playbook for creating VPC in AWS.

The PLaybook will just perform:

1. Create the VPC with the CIDR
2. Then creates the route table
3. Then tags the route table
4. At last create the the route table.

Here is the code:

```
---
- name: To set up internet gateway
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: creating vpc
      ec2_vpc:
        region: ap-northeast-1
        state: present
        cidr_block: 20.0.0.0/16
        resource_tags: { "Name":"Test" }
      register: vpc
    - name: Creating internet gateway for the vpc created
      ec2_vpc_igw:
        region: ap-northeast-1
        state: present
        vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
      register: igw
    - name: Tagging the gateway we just created
      ec2_tag:
        resource: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
        #with_items: igw.gateway_id
        state: present
        region: ap-northeast-1
        tags:
          Name: test-test
    - name: Creating route table
      ec2_vpc_route_table:
        region: ap-northeast-1
        propagating_vgw_ids: yes
        vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
         subnets:
          - '20.0.0.0/16'
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gateway_id: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
```

But when I execute my playbook I am getting the error as follows

```
failed: [172.30.1.237] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450103975.3-140284971977416/ec2_vpc_route_table", line 2411, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450103975.3-140284971977416/ec2_vpc_route_table", line 588, in main
    result = ensure_route_table_present(connection, module)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450103975.3-140284971977416/ec2_vpc_route_table", line 519, in ensur                                                     e_route_table_present
check_mode=check_mode)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1450103975.3-140284971977416/ec2_vpc_route_table", line 398, in ensure_propagation
    dry_run=check_mode)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/vpc/__init__.py", line 1492, in enable_vgw_route_propagation
return self.get_status('EnableVgwRoutePropagation', params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1227, in get_status
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>Gateway.NotAttached</Code><Message>resource     True</Message></Error></Errors><RequestI                                                    D>4f34cefd-08c2-4180-b532-dd6e9e74f7e7</RequestID></Response>
```

Besides the mistakes with the indentations, where am I making the mistakes.
Its creating the VPC, as well as the internet gateway. But while using the route table module. I am getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend creating the internet gateway with the creation of the VPClike this:

```
- name: To set up internet gateway
   hosts: all
   tasks:
     - name: Create VPC and Subnet
       ec2_vpc:
         state: present
         region: ap-northeast-1
         cidr_block: 20.0.0.0/16
         subnets:
           - cidr: 20.0.0.0/16
             resource_tags: {"Name":"Test Subnet"}
         route_tables:
           - subnets:
             - 20.0.0.0/16
             routes:
               - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
                 gw: igw
         wait: yes
         internet_gateway: yes
         resource_tags:
           Name: "Test VPC"
       register: vpc

     - name: get igw
        ec2_vpc_igw:
          vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
          region: ap-northeast-1
          state: present
        register: igw

      - name: Tagging the new internet gateway created
        ec2_tag:
          resource: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
          state: present
          region: ap-northeast-1
          tags:
            Name: test-gateway
```

The 'gw' option can accept 'igw' and will create a internet gateway automatically and you can tag the internet gateway after the creation of the VPC with the registered variable 'vpc'.

Edit:
I updated the playbook and tested it and it works.
use it like that.

Comment: I tried your playbook with little modification by adding the following lines, but it is saying that the igw is not defined.

Comment: - name: Tagging the new internet gateway created
        ec2_tag:
          resource: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
          state: present
          region: ap-northeast-1
          tags:
            Name: test-gateway

Comment: you can use the igw variable only in the vpc creation. to tag the igw you can use vpc registrated variable. in the vpc variable you will have the igw id

Comment: edit: you can't get the igw id from the vpc variable but you can use the module ec2_vpc_igw and give the vpc id and register the result like that:
ec2_vpc_igw:
  vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
  state: present
register: igw
 
- name: Tagging the new internet gateway created
ec2_tag: resource: "{{ igw.gateway_id }}"
 state: present
 region: ap-northeast-1
 tags: Name: test-gateway

Comment: here is the link to the ansible module for referance: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_igw_module.html#examples

Comment: I created the gateway using the ec2_vpc_igw module. But i couldnot get the value of gateway id from the vpc registered value.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Now I got to know how to perform that.

Answer (score 3):

That complete and compact ansible role might help you.

`roles/vpc/defaults/main.yml` file look like this:

```
---
# Variables that can provide as extra vars
VPC_NAME: test
VPC_REGION: us-east-1 # N.Virginia
VPC_CIDR: "172.25.0.0/16"
VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT: "172.25"

# Variables for VPC
vpc_name: "{{ VPC_NAME }}"
vpc_region: "{{ VPC_REGION }}"
vpc_cidr_block: "{{ VPC_CIDR }}"
public_cidr_1: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.10.0/24"
public_az_1: "{{ vpc_region }}a"
public_cidr_2: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.20.0/24"
public_az_2: "{{ vpc_region }}b"
private_cidr_1: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.30.0/24"
private_az_1: "{{ vpc_region }}a"
private_cidr_2: "{{ VPC_CLASS_DEFAULT }}.40.0/24"
private_az_2: "{{ vpc_region }}b"

# Please don't change the variables below, until you know what you are doing
#
# Subnets Defination for VPC
vpc_subnets:
  - cidr: "{{ public_cidr_1 }}" # Public Subnet-1
    az: "{{ public_az_1 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ public_az_1 }}-public_subnet-1", "Type":"Public", "Alias":"Public_Subnet_1" }
  - cidr: "{{ public_cidr_2 }}" # Public Subnet-2
    az: "{{ public_az_2 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ public_az_2 }}-public-subnet-2", "Type":"Public", "Alias":"Public_Subnet_2" }
  - cidr: "{{ private_cidr_1 }}" # Private Subnet-1
    az: "{{ private_az_1 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ private_az_1 }}-private-subnet-1", "Type":"Private", "Alias":"Private_Subnet_1" }
  - cidr: "{{ private_cidr_2 }}" # Private Subnet-2
    az: "{{ private_az_2 }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-{{ private_az_2 }}-private-subnet-2", "Type":"Private", "Alias":"Private_Subnet_2" }
```

Then `roles/vpc/tasks/main.yml` file will be like this:

```
---
- name: Creating an AWS VPC inside mentioned Region
  ec2_vpc:
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state:  present
    cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
    resource_tags: { "Name":"{{ vpc_name }}-vpc", "Environment":"{{ ENVIRONMENT }}" }
    subnets: "{{ vpc_subnets }}" 
    internet_gateway: yes
  register: vpc

- name: Tag the Internet Gateway
  ec2_tag:
    resource: "{{ vpc.igw_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "{{ vpc_name }}-igw"
  register: igw

- name: Set up Public Subnets Route Table
  ec2_vpc_route_table:
    vpc_id: "{{ vpc.vpc_id }}"
    region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
    state: present
    tags:
      Name: "Public-RT-for-{{ vpc_name }}-vpc"
    subnets:
      "{{ vpc.subnets | get_public_subnets_ids('Type','Public') }}"
    routes:
      - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
        gateway_id: "{{ vpc.igw_id }}"
  register: public_rt
```

For complete reference, take a look at this [github repo](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles).

Hope it help you or others.

Comment: Nice one. Notes that instead of implementing your own filter, one could rewrite it as follow: "{{ vpc.subnets | map(attribute('cidr') | list }}

Comment: I use the filter because I want to make distinction between the private subnet id and public subnet id, which is not possible with the method that you have mentioned.

Comment: Fully agree :-) but the initial question was not mentioning private subnet and it is worth mentioning map method as well. Another way to do it would be to create two vars for subnets: vpc_public_subnet and vpc_private_subnet. In that case, the map method can be used on each. Furthemore, the two variables can be merged in a new list if really needed

Comment: didn't get this "the two variables can be merged in a new list if really needed"?

Comment: - name: all_subnets
  set_fact:
    vpc_all_subnets: "{{ vpc_public_subnets }} + {{vpc_private_subnets}}"

- name: all_subnets_debug
  debug: msg="{{ vpc_all_subnets }}"

Answer (score 0):

Remove this entry ...

```
propagating_vgw_ids: yes
```

... from your route table definition. It should work.